# SQL How to use LAG inside SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, analytic-functions

My table (name EPM1):

| TIMESTAMP | INVERTER1POWER | INVERTER2POWER | POWERLIMIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-30T17:19:42.309Z | 100 | 400 | 0.8 |
| 2021-09-30T17:20:42.309Z | 200 | 500 | 0.6 |
| 2021-09-30T17:21:42.309Z | 300 | 600 | 0.7 |

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (INVERTER1POWER+INVERTER2POWER) < (250000*POWERLIMIT) THEN INVERTER1POWER+INVERTER2POWER END) AS SUM1
  FROM EPM1
  WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ(:timefrom) AND TIMESTAMP <= TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ(:timeto)
```

This gives me output:

| SUM1 |
| --- |
| 2100 |

I'd like to have similar single value but in calculation use `POWERLIMIT` from previous row - in this part `(250000*POWERLIMIT)`. So for the first iteration it would be `(100+400)*0` since there's no previous value. Then `(200+500)*0.8` and then `(300+600)*0.6`.

I tried to use LAG function like `LAG(POWERLIMIT, 1, 0)` but can't use it inside SUM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested sub-query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(temp_value) AS sum2
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN INVERTER1POWER+INVERTER2POWER
              < 25000 * LAG(POWERLIMIT, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)
         THEN INVERTER1POWER+INVERTER2POWER
         END AS temp_value
  FROM   epm1
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EPM1 (TIMESTAMP, INVERTER1POWER, INVERTER2POWER, POWERLIMIT) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-09-30 17:19:42.309 UTC', 100, 400, 0.8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-09-30 17:20:42.309 UTC', 200, 500, 0.6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-09-30 17:21:42.309 UTC', 300, 600, 0.7 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | SUM2 |
> | --- |
> | 1600 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=263a6d593040b7530c07476154d38ebe)*